# Laravel, same path on a different subdomain uses wrong controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, url-routing

### Question

How can I set up Laravel routing so that:

- navigating to `mysite.com/login` uses the `LoginController`
- navigating to `somecompany.mysite.com/login` uses the `TenantLoginController`

### What I'm doing

I'd have a Laravel 5.7 app that has a typical login page at say, `mystite.com/login`

I'd like to set up a subdomain for this app like `somecompany.mysite.com` that will have it's own authentication.

I'd like the `somecompany` users to log in at   `somecompany.mysite.com/login`

---

### What I've tried

The route definition for the main site login

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth', 'middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('login',   'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
});
```

The rout definition for the subsomain login

```
Route::domain('somecompany.mysite.com')->group(function ($router) {
    $router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Tenant\Auth', 'middleware' => ['web']], function($router) {
        $router->get('login',   'TenantLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('somecompany.login');
    });
});
```

---

### What Happened

I can navigate to `somecompany.mysite.com/login` and the URL bar says `somecompany.mysite.com/login` but when I do, the request is actually routed to the `'LoginController@showLoginForm'` controller not the expected `'TenantLoginController@showLoginForm'` and the typical login form is desplayed, not the subdomain's login form.

If I change the path to `$router->get('tenant-login'` and navigate to `somecompany.mysite.com/tenant-login` the subdomain login form is shown, and `somecompany.mysite.com/login` shows the main login form.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but since you did not specify a domain in the first route (handled by `LoginController`), it should also be valid for the `somecompany.mysite.com` subdomain. So I would suggest trying to add more specificity to that first route, enclosing it with `Route::domain('mysite.com')`? The Laravel router always takes the first matching route, and that first one matches just fine in the end.

Comment: @LupinityLabs You my friend are 100% right! If I wrap the the main routes in a domain call, it all works as expected. Throw up an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help! Done, thanks :-)

Comment: You can change the order of routes definition. First put specific domain routes, then put general routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not specify a domain in the first route (handled by `LoginController`), it should also be valid for the `somecompany.mysite.com` subdomain.

To work around that, I would suggest trying to add more specificity to that first route, enclosing it with `Route::domain('mysite.com')`.

The Laravel router always takes the first matching route, and that first one matches just fine in the end.

Comment: Laravel takes the last loaded route not first matching. If you have multiple same routes the one that is last loaded/registered will be triggered. Just like css class.